# Why does the first loop result to 0 instead of 1?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the first loop prints out 0 instead of 1. Doesn't the i++ apply to the first loop?

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         console.log('i');
    }
```

Comment: `i++` is the `final-expression`, it is evaluated at the end of each loop not before. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: no, it's at the end of every loop, it's the incrementing clause, the initialization clause is the first one where you start your loop. Why structure the language so it's less obvious where you'll start.

Comment: Are you new to programming?

Comment: read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Actually, it prints out the letter `i` three times. To print the *value* of `i`, remove the quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

No i++ increments only after executing logic in the loop